# Problem on Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

**How many integers $1, 2,....., 11000$ are invertible modulo $880$?**

$880$ can be rewritten as $2^4\cdot5\cdot11$.

So I am supposed to find the number of integers in this range that have $2$, $5$ or $11$ as a divisor and then subtract that value from $11000$.

So If I divide $11000$ by each of $2$, $5$ and $11$, I get cardinalities of $5500$, $2200$, and $1000$ respectively. But how exactly am I supposed to find how many integers there are that have both $2$ and $5$ as a divisor, $2$ and $11$ as a divisor, and $5$ and $11$ as a divisor? How am I supposed to find the amount of integers that have all three numbers as a divisor?

Any help?

Comment: An integer has $2$ and $5$ as a divisor if and only if it has _____ as a divisor. Similar logic for the other pairs (since they're relatively prime). Analogously, an integer is a multiple of $2$, $5$, and $11$ if and only if it's a multiple of ______. The work is routine, although a little tedious.

Comment: @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг Thank you for your reply but I don't believe 8800 is the answer. I am not entirely familiar with your method either. With the help received above and below I performed the following calculation with the cardinalities and the principle of inclusion-exclusion: 5500 + 2200 + 1000 - 1100 - 500 - 200 + 100 = 7000 integers that have either 2, 5 or 11 as a divisor. Therefore, 11000-7000 = 4000 integers invertible modulo 880. Could you please double check? Or maybe I am wrong...

Comment: That method is correct, but they calculated $11000/880$ and $\phi(880)$ wrong. It should be $11000=12.5\times 880$ and $\phi(880)=320$ and $12.5 \times 320=4000$, the correct answer

Comment: @sktsasus Do pardon me : how on earth did I think that $11000 = 880 \times 25$?  Besides, I even got $\phi(880)$ wrong. As Riley says, the method would've given the answer. You are correct too.

Comment: OK I see now! Thanks for introducing this new method!

Comment: In case you are wondering why that method works, $\phi(n)$ is called the Euler totient function. It is defined as the number of integers in $1,\dots,n$ that are coprime to $n$. From that definition, much study yields the formula $$\phi(n)=n\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{p_1}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{1}{p_k}\right)$$ where the $p_i$ are the prime factors of $n$. Since the numbers coprime to $n$ are precisely the invertible elements modulo $n$, it is clear why this method works.

Comment: @Riley Wow that's interesting! I will be sure to keep this in mind from now on! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The inclusion-exclusion principle states that $$\#(A\cup B)=\#(A)+\#(B)-\#(A\cap B)$$

Generalizing this, we also find that $$\#(A\cup B \cup C)=\#(A)+\#(B)+\#(C)-\#(A\cap B) - \#(A\cap C)-\#(B\cap C)+\#(A\cap B\cap C)$$

So, if we let $A,B,C$ be the sets of all integers in $[0,11000]$ divisible by $2$, $5$, and $11$, respectively, the number of invertible elements modulo $880$ is simply the quantity $11000-\#(A\cup B \cup C)$. So, all we need to know is the value of each term in the above formula. But $\#(A\cap B)$ is the number of integers in $[0,11000]$ divisible by $2$ and $5$, i.e. divisible by $2\cdot 5=10$. Similarly, you can find out the meanings of the other terms and plug them into the formula to get your result.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the set of integers which are divisible by $n$ in the range $\{1,2,\cdots,11000\}$ by $N(n)$. We wish to find $|N(2)\cup N(5)\cup N(11)|$. We can use inclusion exclusion.

$$|N(2)\cup N(5)\cup N(11)|=|N(2)|+|N(5)|+|N(11)|-|N(2)\cap N(5)|-|N(2)\cap N(11)|-|N(5)\cap N(11)|+|N(2)\cap N(5)\cap N(11)|$$

As stated in the comments, to find the size of the intersections, you need to find out how many integers are divisible by multiple numbers. If a number is divisible by $x$ and is divisible by $y$, and $x$ and $y$ are coprime (as they are in this example, $2$,$5$,$11$), then the number is divisible by $xy$. Use this to find the size of the set.